# Do paid investment newsletters/services offer a significant return on investment?

Tags: stocks, news, services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Investment Research websites worth their premiums?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/are-investment-research-websites-worth-their-premiums)

Do paid investment newsletters/services offer a significant return on investment?

Comment: Well. I suppose that all depends on what you do with the information and what other information you have access to.

Comment: Same question in different words.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fallacy (called "adverse selection?" someone correct, please) in which say, a mutual fund company introduces funds, but each year or two manages to eliminate the poorly performing funds. After sufficient time has passed, their advertising brags about the remarkable returns from their family of funds.

In the world of newsletters, similar effects occur, so today's offering will likely appear to have outperformed the market, if only because underperforming newsletters tend to cease publication.

Whether those that are publishing today will continue their streaks can't be predicted. What I can offer you, though, id the name [Mark Hulbert](http://www.marketwatch.com/Journalists/Mark_Hulbert) who offers a newsletter whose raison d'etre is the tracking of the performance of financial newsletters.